# Core Graphics memory leak

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, core-graphics

The analyser is flagging up a memory issue. Normally I would use autorelease but this is not possible in Core Foundation. How do I fix this error?

[image: Screen shot of error]

```
- (CGMutablePathRef)NewCGMutablePathRefCreateWithRoundedRectForRect:(CGRect)rect andRadius:(CGFloat)radius andMargin:(CGFloat)margin andrIndent:(CGFloat)rIndent andlIndent:(CGFloat)lIndent
{
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect) + margin);
CGPathAddArcToPoint(path, NULL, CGRectGetMaxX(rect) - margin - rIndent, CGRectGetMinY(rect) + margin, CGRectGetMaxX(rect) - margin - rIndent, CGRectGetMaxY(rect) - margin, radius);
CGPathAddArcToPoint(path, NULL, CGRectGetMaxX(rect) - margin - rIndent, CGRectGetMaxY(rect) - margin, CGRectGetMinX(rect) + margin + lIndent, CGRectGetMaxY(rect) - margin, radius);
CGPathAddArcToPoint(path, NULL, CGRectGetMinX(rect) + margin + lIndent, CGRectGetMaxY(rect) - margin, CGRectGetMinX(rect) + margin + lIndent, CGRectGetMinY(rect) + margin, radius);
CGPathAddArcToPoint(path, NULL, CGRectGetMinX(rect) + margin + lIndent, CGRectGetMinY(rect) + margin, CGRectGetMaxX(rect) - margin, CGRectGetMinY(rect) +margin, radius);
CGPathCloseSubpath(path);


return path;
}
```

After adding the release path code as suggested I get another error plus the original one?

[image: additional screen shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the path outside and try passing just the reference of this path in your method. Then you can release the path in the same scope, where you called your method. Memory leak issue will go away.

Answer (score 4):

```
CFRelease(path);
```

[CoreFoundation reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFTypeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFRelease)

use CFRelease after you don't need the path anymore.

```
CGMutablePathRef path = [obj NewCGMutablePathRefCreateWithRoundedRectForRect:rect andRadius:radius andMargin:margin andrIndent:rIndent andlIndent:lIndent];
//do something with path, then release it
CFRelease(path);
```

Another thing is methods returning objects that are not autoreleased have to begin with:

- alloc
- copy
- new
- retain

so you should name your method:
newCGMutablePathRefCreateWithRoundedRectForRect
instead of:
NewCGMutablePathRefCreateWithRoundedRectForRect

Comment: Thanks for the reply. At what point should I release it, If I do it before the return, it will return NULL?

Comment: no you have to release it at some other point, see updated answer

Comment: I attempted that but was met with an additional error, see edit above

Comment: thats because of your method naming, see again updated answer

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue in two easy steps:

1. Rename the method from `NewCGMutablePathRefCreateWithRoundedRectForRect` to `CreateCGMutablePathRefWithRoundedRectForRect`. The important part of renaming it is that the method starts with `Create`, which tells the static analyzer that your method returns an object that needs to be released and will stop the warning that you're seeing.
2. Release the returned `CGPathRef` by calling `CGPathRelease`.

Answer (score 0):

```
CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
```

Add this code, before returning that variable `path`.

Comment: Oh. In that case you can use `CGPathRelease`.

Comment: Wont that return NULL?

Answer (score 0):

Release the path variable after you finish using it. For eg:

in some other method in your code you will be using this path rt?

say

CGMutablePathRef path = [obj NewCGMutablePathRefCreateWithRoundedRectForRect:rect andRadius:radius andMargin:margin andrIndent:rIndent andlIndent:lIndent];

.......
.......

CFRelease(path);